# Is it possible to do object-detection on 2d structures like triangle with Spark AR application, this will then redirect to a video hosted somewhere

Tags: instagram, yolov5, spark-ar-studio

Basically,
I wanted to know if I can make a yolo based object detection model incorporate it with the Spark AR application and create a filter that can then detect a triangle(2d).This is let's say a logo, and then after it successfully has detected it, the end-user will be directed to a Video.
Is it at all possible to do so? I am having a hard time finding relevant examples, and this is my first time creating such an application.
Any help would be appreciated
Thank you!

I haven't tried anything yet and looking for advice